# Using SQL Exists but having issues

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure which inserts records from a lab, and for months it has been inserting records and working. But in the last month something has changed and my record check stopped working.

The SampleNames exist and I can do a query to locate the sample name. What might be the issue?

I can get it to sort of work if I replace the `If Exists` with this:

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT [SampleName] FROM [dbo].[HPLC_Sample] 
           WHERE [SampleName] LIKE '%' + UPPER(@SampleName) + '%')
```

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_HPLC_Params]
    @SampleName nvarchar(32),
    @DataFile nvarchar(max),
    @AcqInstrument nvarchar(50),
    @AnalysisDate datetime,
    @ResultsCreated datetime,
    @ResCreatedBy nvarchar(50),
    @AcqMethod nvarchar(50),
    @InjDate datetime,
    @AcqOp datetime,
    @SeqLine int,
    @Location int,
    @Inj int,
    @InjVol int,
    @ActualInj int,
    @SeqFile nvarchar(50),
    @StartPress float,
    @StopPress float, 
    @StartFlow float,
    @StopFlow float,
    @SortBy nvarchar(50),
    @CalbDTCreate datetime,
    @CalbDTMod datetime,
    @PeakID nchar(10),
    @Muliplier int,
    @Dilution int,
    @UnCalPeaks nchar(10),
    @NumSignals int,
    @NumErrors int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SampleID AS smallint
    
    IF EXISTS (SELECT [SampleName] FROM [dbo].[HPLC_Sample] 
               WHERE [SampleName] = @SampleName)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @SampleID = [SampleID] 
        FROM [dbo].[HPLC_Sample] 
        WHERE [SampleName] = @SampleName
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO HPLC_Sample([SampleName])   
        VALUES (UPPER(@SampleName))

        SELECT @SampleID = [SampleID] 
        FROM [dbo].[HPLC_Sample] 
        WHERE [SampleName] = @SampleName
    END
END
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO HPLC_Params([SampleID], [Data File], [Acq Instrument], [Analysis Date], [Results Created],
                [Results Created By], [Acq Method], [Injection Date], [Acq Operator],
                [Seq Line], [Location], [Inj], [Inj Volume], 
                [Actual Inj Volume], [Sequence File], [Start Pressure], [Stop Pressure],
                [Start Flow], [Stop Flow], [Sorted By], [Calib Data Created],
                [Calib Data Modified], [Peak ID], [Multiplier],[Dilution],
                [Uncalibrated Peaks], [Number of Signals], [Number of Errors])  
        VALUES (@SampleID, @DataFile, @AcqInstrument, @AnalysisDate, @ResultsCreated,
                @ResCreatedBy, @AcqMethod, @InjDate, @AcqOp,
                @SeqLine, @Location, @Inj, @InjVol,
                @ActualInj, @SeqFile, @StartPress, @StopPress, 
                @StartFlow, @StopFlow, @SortBy, @CalbDTCreate,
                @CalbDTMod, @PeakID, @Muliplier, @Dilution,
                @UnCalPeaks, @NumSignals, @NumErrors)
    END 
END
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help. When you say "not working" what happens?

Comment: What do you mean by "stopped working"? What do you mean by "sort of get it to work"? If I were to guess, I think you mean your procedure seems to be executing the `else` block when you don't expect it to be? If so, I would further guess that there is data in the `[Sample Name]` column containing non-printable or whitespace characters that will not be easily visible if you "check" the data in the SSMS results pane. As a *very* rough first pass, you might see if any results come from a a select `where [Sample Name] like '%[^0-9A-Z ]%'`

Comment: Actually allmhuran is correct, the Exists clause can not find any sample names which should be names like "FERM A", "FERM B", FERM C", "FERM D".  So what happens is the else statement trips and Inserts a name but the name is Null. I did a check on data in the Sample Name column and only two records return with the unseen chacters.   Both do not get selected and have not.  

But the statement pertaining to the prefix of sp_, that was interesting.  And might actually be the issue here.  But I do not currently have rights to the software which calls this stored procedure.

Comment: If the procedure is inserting rows with a `null` sample name into the `HPLC_Sample` table, then the code calling the procedure is passing `null` for the `@SampleName` parameter.

Comment: @allmhuran Hum.  It did seem strange that this software has been running for 10 months and now it can not locate the Sample Names.  I have seen the files that the software is to process and they have Sample Names.  So something changed.

Comment: If you don't want NULL values for SampleName, then change the definition of the column. And since your procedure code assumes SampleName is unique, then you should make it so with a constraint. Lastly, protect the database. Throw an error when the SampleName parameter is null or otherwise "not good".

Comment: Try executing `select cast(SampleName as varbinary(max))` for one/some of the rows that the stored procedure isn't finding normally. A likely issue will be something like an ETL ingestion process not stripping off control characters properly, so investigating this I'd expect to see the offending varbinary values ending with something like `0D00` (ASCII 13, carriage return) or `0A00` (ASCII 10, linefeed) or similar.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Good point, I always do not know how the Lab techs navigate through the entries when preparing the samples.  They could very well be passing in the ASCII and the code isn't trimming it.  Really puzzling this, I have another site which uses the exactly same code and they have never seen this issue. This site has updated Lab software and poof broken.

Comment: @SMor Very good idea, and I was getting to that.  I inherited the system and our Database guy is out on personal leave.  Database and SQL isn't my forte and why I come to you all, my mentors.  I need to look up how to prevent Nulls.  I got nailed with It changing the rights on the desktop this runs on today.  Just fun